# Ansible Error : Timeout (3s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt Using Python

Tags: python, ansible

Below is a python code to trigger Ansible. I tried in 1.9 and 2.0 and 2.1 Ansible.

Also tried --disablefingerprint in pre-run. No luck.

```
Options = namedtuple('Options', ['listtags', 'listtasks', 'listhosts', 'syntax', 'connection','module_path', 'forks', 'remote_user', 'private_key_file', 'ssh_common_args', 'ssh_extra_args', 'sftp_extra_args', 'scp_extra_args', 'verbosity', 'check','become','become_method','become_user'])
options = Options(listtags=False, listtasks=False, listhosts=False, syntax=False, connection='smart', module_path=None, forks=2, remote_user='None', private_key_file='/Users/adm/mannoj.pem', ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None, sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None,verbosity=True, check=False,become=True,become_method='su',become_user='root')

variable_manager.extra_vars = {'hosts': 'db_machines'} # This can accomodate various other command line arguments.

passwords = {}

pbex = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path], inventory=inventory, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader, options=options, passwords=None)

results = pbex.run()
}
```

It works fine with normal ansible cli , but not as a python.

Answer (score 0):

Got it successfully executed (in a hacky way). Trust me no subprocess :)

For some reason remote user is not picking up via python way of executing. It picks the user that python is getting executed.

Scenario 1 : changed verbose to 5.

- Execute Python

> ```
> fatal: [db1.mysql.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! Timeout (5s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}
> ERROR:p=6392 u=adm | :fatal: [db1.mysql.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! Timeout (5s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}
> ```

- Tried to add user "adm" on destination server "db1.mysql.com" and give NOPASSWD sudo to that user.
- Now it executes successfully.

Tried the other way by adding the ansible user on my local but no luck.

remote_user or ssh related arguments are picked rightly via python for me. Also not enough documents are available for each arguments in Python.